How to use a newer python version for root without changing the system wide installation of python?
I need to create a VirtualBox instance of Ubuntu on Windows 10, but I need to run python version 3.11 as root on that VM. How can I install a newer version of python to be run as root without changing the system python version?
I used pyenv to install different versions of python, and then to install a tool system wide (no virtual environment). Here I need to run some code as root in order to capture traffic from a network device (for which I need root access as far as I know).

Why do you need to run python as root? You can easily run a particular python version without root, using Anaconda/Miniconda.

I will clarify this, but as far as I know there is a tool that must be run as root.

Can you provide more details? Which tool you are trying to run that does not work without python3.11 as root?

An internal tool in our company. But I will clarify/try to run it as a normal user using pyenv or something

Does it work with python3.12? If so, then upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04, and it will solve the issue.

I need root access to capture packets on the network devices.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
